# link to github file without /master/tree

Tags: url, github

I want a link to my project e.g.,

`http://github.com/folder1/folder2/GUI`.

While `http://github.com/folder1/folder2` works fine,

`http://github.com/folder1/folder2/GUI` DOES not.

It only works as

`http://github.com/folder1/folder2/tree/master/GUI`

which is really "ugly" to insert in a paper...

P.S. Needless to say that `/GUI` folder exists and has files inside...

Comment: How are you generating these links?

Comment: I just copy them from the url from the browser, after I visit my project in github